# Проблема подгрузки части сайта, если заходишь с www

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть сайт, у него есть блок, который подгружается с помощью `js`, когда заходишь на сайт `http://site.ru` - все грузит нормально, но когда заходишь `www.site.ru` почему-то не подгружает - в чем проблема?

Код js:

```
function showvideos()

{
    $.ajax({

        url: "http://site.ru/php/video.php",

        cache: false,

        success: function(html){

            $("#videosshow").html(html);

        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
2. http://enable-cors.org/client.html

Используйте абсолютный путь:

```
function showvideos(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/php/video.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#videosshow").html(html);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, написал вопрос, тут же исправил на абсолютный путь и стало работать, блин и так всегда почему-то... Но все равно спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте либо без указания домена:

```
function showvideos()

{
    $.ajax({

        url: "/php/video.php",

        cache: false,

        success: function(html){

            $("#videosshow").html(html);

        }

    });

};
```

либо, в video.php пропишите до начала вывода [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/):

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if (preg_match('/^.+\.site.ru$|^site.ru$/',$http_origin)) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
}
```